# Optimizing Opportunities with Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I was looking through some code and came across this method that takes an HTML Header value (i.e. Content-Disposition=inline;filename=foo.bar) and parses it into a map separated by the semi-colon's into key=value pairs.  At first it looked like a good candidate for optimization using a stream, but after I implemented it, the fact that I can't reuse the computed String.indexOf('=') value means the string must be scanned 3 times, which is actually less optimal than the original.  I'm perfectly aware that there are many instances where Streams aren't the right tool for the job, but I was wondering if I had just missed some technique that could allow the Stream to be as performant/more performant than the initial code.

```
  /**
   * Convert a Header Value String into a Map
   *
   * @param value The Header Value
   * @return The data Map
   */
  private static Map<String,String> headerMap (String value) {
    int eq;
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(String entry : value.split(";")) {
      if((eq = entry.indexOf('=')) != -1) {
        map.put(entry.substring(0,eq),entry.substring(eq + 1));
      }
    }
    return map;

    return Stream.of(value.split(";")).filter(entry -> entry.indexOf('=') != -1).collect(Collectors.));
  } //headerMap
```

My attempt at Streaming it:

```
  /**
   * Convert a Header Value String into a Map
   *
   * @param value The Header Value
   * @return The data Map
   */
  private static Map<String,String> headerMap (String value) {
    return Stream.of(value.split(";")).filter(entry -> entry.indexOf('=') != -1).collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.substring(0,entry.indexOf('=')),entry -> entry.substring(entry.substring(entry.indexOf('=') + 1))));
  } //headerMap
```

Comment: Generally speaking, streams make code shorter, and allow you to parallelize more easily, but you should not expect them to make your code faster in general.

Comment: Agreed, but using them knowing that they are probably going to slow down the code, just to save a little code space, would not be advised.  In most cases you can gain speed (or at least not lose speed) with well devised stream chains.  I'm hoping I missed something in my attempt that someone more well versed will be able to point out.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy either of those claims, actually -- I'm perfectly happy to accept some slowdown in exchange for improved code readability, but I'm not certain streams can ever result in speed improvements (other than eased parallelization).  Streams are just a library; the JIT is well optimized for them, but I would be at least mildly surprised if they beat well-tuned imperative code.

Comment: Stream is not good for parsers, which are usually stateful. And your original parsing code seems too brittle, missing many corner cases. here's [my parser](https://github.com/zhong-j-yu/bayou/blob/0.9/src/bayou/mime/TokenParams.java#L105) for such headers

Answer (score 5):

This solution looks for `'='` only once:

```
private static Map<String, String> headerMap(String value) {
    return Stream.of(value.split(";"))
            .map(s -> s.split("=", 2))
            .filter(arr -> arr.length == 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(arr -> arr[0], arr -> arr[1]));
}
```

Note that here the fast-path for `String.split` is used, thus regular expression is not actually created.

Note that using Guava you can do this in quite clean way even prior to Java-8:

```
private static Map<String, String> headerMap(String value) {
    return Splitter.on( ';' ).withKeyValueSeparator( '=' ).split( value );
}
```

In general I would advise you against manual parsing of HTTP headers. There are many caveats there. See, for example, how it's [implemented](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/org/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser.java#307) in Apache HTTP library. Use libraries.

Comment: Nice!  I will have to add it to @Tunaki 's JMH Benchmark and try them all out head-to-head.  I was really using this as an example of an optimization opportunity, not as the proper way to parse HTTP Headers.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with the following code:

```
private static Map<String, String> headerMap(String value) {
    return Stream.of(value.split(";"))
                .filter(entry -> entry.indexOf('=') != -1)
                .map(entry -> {
                    int i = entry.indexOf('=');
                    return new String[] { entry.substring(0, i), entry.substring(i + 1) };
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(array -> array[0], array -> array[1]));
}
```

It only scans for the `entry` two times, by storing the key and value inside an array of size 2. I'm not sure it will be as performant as the `for` loop since we are creating another Object to serve just as a holder.

Another solution that scans the `entry` only one time is this, although I'm not very found of it:

```
private static Map<String, String> headerMap(String value) {
    return Stream.of(value.split(";"))
            .map(entry -> {
                int i = entry.indexOf('=');
                if (i == -1) {
                    return null;
                }
                return new String[] { entry.substring(0, i), entry.substring(i + 1) };
            })
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(array -> array[0], array -> array[1]));
}
```

I realized a JMH benchmark to test this. Following is the benchmark code:

```
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, time = 1000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@Fork(3)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class StreamTest {

    private static final String VALUE = "Accept=text/plain;"
        + "Accept-Charset=utf-8;"
        + "Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate;"
        + "Accept-Language=en-US;"
        + "Accept-Datetime=Thu, 31 May 2007 20:35:00 GMT;"
        + "Cache-Control=no-cache;"
        + "Connection=keep-alive;"
        + "Content-Length=348;"
        + "Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded;"
        + "Date=Tue, 15 Nov 1994 08:12:31 GMT;"
        + "Expect=100-continue;"
        + "Max-Forwards=10;"
        + "Pragma=no-cache";

    @Benchmark
    public void loop() {
        int eq;
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (String entry : VALUE.split(";")) {
            if ((eq = entry.indexOf('=')) != -1) {
                map.put(entry.substring(0, eq), entry.substring(eq + 1));
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void stream1() {
        Stream.of(VALUE.split(";"))
        .filter(entry -> entry.indexOf('=') != -1)
        .map(entry -> {
            int i = entry.indexOf('=');
            return new String[] { entry.substring(0, i), entry.substring(i + 1) };
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(array -> array[0], array -> array[1]));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void stream2() {
        Stream.of(VALUE.split(";"))
        .map(entry -> {
            int i = entry.indexOf('=');
            if (i == -1) {
                return null;
            }
            return new String[] { entry.substring(0, i), entry.substring(i + 1) };
        })
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(array -> array[0], array -> array[1]));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         Main.main(args);
    }

}
```

and this is the result (*Code i5 3230M CPU @ 2.60 GHz, Windows 10, Oracle JDK 1.8.0_25*):

```
Benchmark           Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
StreamTest.loop     avgt   30  1,541 ± 0,038  us/op
StreamTest.stream1  avgt   30  1,633 ± 0,042  us/op
StreamTest.stream2  avgt   30  1,604 ± 0,058  us/op
```

What this demonstrates is that both the streams solution and the for loop are actually equivalent in terms of performance.

Comment: That's true, but adding an additional Object creation in there probably negates the benefit of removing the string scan.  Especially since the size of HTTP Header Strings is typically fairly short.

Comment: Using a spliterator on ; would be better, I think. Then process each element in parallel.

Comment: Wow, nicely done.  I've never used that tool, I'll definitely have to give it a try.

Comment: @ChrisDennett, how would a Spliterator be an advantage in this situation?  I'm not seeing the advantage.

Comment: You read the entire string in advance and generate an array of strings, when that doesn't need to be done.